# Splitting a string of numbers into an array of strings to turn into integers - Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, numberformatexception

I am trying to break down lines in a file from strings to arrays of strings, each with a number. Then I am trying to convert each string to an integer value to use for my code.  It is giving me a number format exception.  Is there some way I'm doing it wrong.

16.0 0.0 30.0
0.0 0.0 30.0
0.0 10.0 30.0
8.0 16.0 54.0
16.0 0.0 54.0
16.0 0.0 54.0
0.0 0.0 54.0
0.0 10.0 54.0
5   1   5   4   3   2
5   6   7   8   9   10
4   7   2   3   8split works for edges
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5    1   5   4   3   2"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Transformation.numPoly; i ++) {
         String line = Transformation.scanner.nextLine();  // file from another object. 
         System.out.println(line); // ensure line is read. 
           String[] theseEdges = line.split(" "); // split along spaces. 
           System.out.println("split works for edges"); 
           int numEdges = Integer.parseInt(theseEdges[0].trim());// find first number of of string to use for program. 
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(theseEdges)); //
```

It gave me a number format exception.  The spacing in the string it reads in the error message is different than the one in the file or printed by the code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You're file seems to contain floating point values and yet you are using `Integer.parseInt`. What do you think `Integer.parseInt("8.0");` does?

Comment: when I am reading the lines with floating points, I use Double.parseDouble() and it works.  When I am reading the lines where I need them to be natural numbers or indexes, I use pareseInt.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I should paste the text?

Comment: T.J.Foster yes indeed! Just paste it as text, and please also read the link that OH GOD SPIDERS posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some numbers separated by tabs. If you want to split on *any* whitespace, you can use the `\s` regex metacharacter:

```
String[] theseEdges = line.split("\\s+"); // split along whitespaces
```